# Python- Openpyxl works in console but fails to import

Tags: python, elementtree, importerror, openpyxl

I am having an issue getting openpyxl to write to an Excel file, when I run the following code in the PyCharm Python console it works fine but when I create & run the `.py` file I get the following error :

> C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python27/virtualenv-15.0.1/virtualenv/test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Python27/virtualenv-15.0.1/virtualenv/test.py", line 1, in 
>       from openpyxl import Workbook
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl__init__.py", line 28, in 
>       from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook__init__.py", line 5, in 
>       from .workbook import *
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 7, in 
>       from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .worksheet import *
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 34, in 
>       from openpyxl.cell import Cell
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .cell import *
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 44, in 
>       from openpyxl.styles import numbers, is_date_format
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from openpyxl.descriptors import Typed
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .base import *
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 12, in 
>       from openpyxl.xml.functions import Element
>     File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnv1\VirtualEnv1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\xml\functions.py", line 41, in 
>       from xml.etree.ElementTree import (
>   ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
>   Process finished with exit code 1

I installed from https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/index.html and am using the virtual environment as recommended. I also downloaded the elementtree package to the virtual environment but the script still fails. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet()
ws1.title = "worksheet1"

c = ws1['A4']

ws1['A4'] = 15

cell_range = ws1['A1':'C2']

for row in ws1.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
    for cell in row:
        print cell

wb.save('balances.xlsx')
```

[Console run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmuG9.png)

Comment: Looks like the venv isn't set up quite right as `xml.etree.ElementTree` is part of the standard library. I don't know much about setting venvs up in PyCharm but I think that's where the issue is. I always set up venvs independently of any IDE and then configure the project accordingly.

Comment: Yup, looks like it was an issue with the PyCharm venv...created a new one and it's working great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by creating a new PyCharm virtual environment and not selecting the "Inherit global site packages" checkbox:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/creating-virtual-environment.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 0):

Where does your script use etree.ElementTree? This worked for me fine in the console:

```
$ virtualenv .venv
$ . .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install openpyxl

$ tee test.py << 'EOF'
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet()
ws1.title = "worksheet1"

c = ws1['A4']

ws1['A4'] = 15

cell_range = ws1['A1':'C2']

for row in ws1.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
    for cell in row:
        print cell

wb.save('balances.xlsx')

EOF

$ python test.py
```

Comment: I don't use etree.ElementTree in my script, however the openpyxl scripts use it extensively. The code works fine for me in the console as well, but I run into the issue when I save and run as a .py.

Comment: With 'in the console' you mean in the python interactive interpreter? In my answer, I create a file 'test.py' and run it without any errors. As far as I can see the code you posted is not using etree.ElementTree.

Comment: That's correct, by console I meant the interactive interpreter- see the "Console run" image above that runs without issue. I've also posted the full error description, the issue is that openpyxl fails when calling etree.ElementTree